# .slideUp() jQuery command not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide every nav link but the first in my nav bar. The `slideUp()` function isn't hiding them though. I have a loop that is supposed to check if the nav link has the "first" class. If it has the "first" class, the link remains there. If the nav link doesn't have the "first" class, it's supposed to hide it with the slideup animation; but it doesn't.

This is my html:

```
<nav>
    <ul id='nav'>
        <li><a href="index.php"><icon><img src="images/home-icon.png"></icon>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="skillsets.php"><icon><img src="images/skills-icon.png"></icon>Skillsets</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.php"><icon><img src="images/gallery-icon.png"></icon>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php"><icon><img src="images/about-icon.png"></icon>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php"><icon><img src="images/contact-icon.png"></icon>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my javascript:

```
var is_mobile = false,
    page = document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ul = $('nav > ul'),
        li = ul.children('li'),
        href = li.find('a[href*="'+page+'"]'),
        is404 = true;
    if($('#mobile').css('display')=='none') {
        is_mobile = true;       
    }
    if(is_mobile) {
        orderList();
        prepareList();
    }
    /************************************************************/
    /* Reorders the list relative to the page the user is on   */
    /**********************************************************/
    function orderList() {
        //move element to top
        ul.prepend(href.parent());
        //set top elements class to "top"
        $(href).attr( "class", "top" );
        if(page != ""){
            //loop through the nav elements
            li.children('a').each(function(){
                //if the name of the page the user is on matches one of the nav links execute the command
                if (page == $(this).attr('href')) {
                    is404 = false;
                }
            });
            if (is404) {
                //if the user is on a page not in the nav, add a 404 link at the top of the nav
                ul.prepend("<li><a href='404NotFound.php' class='top'><icon><img src='images/404-icon.png'></icon>404</a></li>");
            }else{
                //set top links' class to "top"
                $(href).attr( "class", "top" );
            }
        }
    };
    /*****************************************************************/
    /* Prepares the list to be dynamically expandable/collapsible   */
    /***************************************************************/
    function prepareList() {
        //loop through the nav elements and differentiate the first nav link and the remaining nav links
        li.children('a').each(function(){
            //check if the link has the class: "first"
            if (first == $(this).attr('class')) {// attribute value matches variable value
                //make the first nav link function as the button to open and close the nav

            } else {// attribute doesn't exist, or its value doesn't match variable value
                //hide the remaining nav links with a slideUp animation
                $(this).slideUp("slow");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any ideas guys? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write "first" instead of first in script..

Write like this
    if ("first" == $(this).attr('class'))
Instead of 
    if (first == $(this).attr('class'))

it treated first as a variable instead of string in your case.

Comment: you can use this $(this).parent().slideUp("slow"); instead of  $(this).slideUp("slow"); to hide li

Answer (score 0):

Using .hasClass method you can check the class is present or not

Just change your prepareList function as

```
function prepareList() {
            //loop through the nav elements and differentiate the first nav link and the remaining nav links
            li.children('a').each(function(){
                //check if the link has the class: "first"
                if($(this).hasClass("first")){

                }
                else{
                    $(this).slideUp("slow");
                }
            });
        }
```